# In "Estoy en la gloria", should "gloria" be capitalized?

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

Given the following text:

> Estoy en la gloria.

Here "gloria" is not a proper name, but alludes to being in heaven. Should it be capitalized?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fine like that. "Estar en la gloria" means that you are really good, or relaxed. In this case, "gloria" is a common name, not capitalized.

*Native speaker from Spain here :D